# Volume too loud on alert when AirPods connect or disconnect

Tags: bluetooth, sound-volume, airpods

When my AirPods (1st generation) connect or disconnect from my MacBook, as they are wont to do when not actively playing audio, they make a loud “bong” sound as an audible notice to the user. Even more annoying, it is usually a double “bong” as the inexplicable disconnect-reconnect comes rapidly in succession.

The volume of the “bong” alert seems unrelated to the low volume of my Mac.

The disconnect/reconnect happens at least once or twice every session I use the AirPods. The batteries are fully charged on each session. I almost never run the batteries down.

➥ Is there a way to lower the volume of that “bong” noise?

Comment: Does this sound also happen when the battery is low? If so is it really loud then as well?

Comment: It sounds like an issue with your AirPods specifically, my connection noise isn’t too loud. Is it loud when connecting to other devices? May want to bring them into an apple store. Could also test the volume with a friends’ pair or buy a new pair and then return them.

Comment: same here when i connect pc or android. if i gethart attack i will sue their asses:)